# How can I reuse mapping in linq select statement

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities, mapping

I want to reuse mapping in select statement. 
I'm not able to convert sequence to list, array and so on, because query is used in web api with odata and I don't want to extract all data if odata query requires only one page.

Currently I'm using expression for extracting mapping

```
Expression<Func<Event, EventModel>> EventToEventModelExpression = ...


var events = (DbContext.Events
                .Where(...)
                .Select(EventToEventModelExpression));
```

But I don't know how to use it with selecting objects that contain property of type `EventModel`
For example

```
(from evt in DbContext.Events
    where evt.Business.Id == CurrentBusinessId
    let orders = DbContext.OrderItems.Where(oi => oi.EventId == evt.Id)
    select new
    {
        Event = ??? // how can I apply mapping by using expression
        TicketSold = orders.Count()
    })
```

Now I put Event to IQueryable and use Select then FirstOrDefault.

```
(from evt in DbContext.Events
        where evt.Business.Id == CurrentBusinessId
        let orders = DbContext.OrderItems.Where(oi => oi.EventId == evt.Id)
        select new
        {
            Event = new[] { evt }.AsQueryable(),
            TicketSold = orders.Count()
        }))Select(x => new
        {
            Event = x.Event.Select(exp).FirstOrDefault(),
            ...
        }
```

Is there other way to perfrom this? It looks weird with creating array and casting it to IQuryable, but I didn't find other way.